# Database for customer and it family members

Tags: sql, database, c#-4.0

i want Create database for customer and its family members
`customer`  has `id,name,age,occupation` and family
 `membres` has `name,age,relation ship` filed respectively..
and how to insert value into that db by using C# windows application.
plz help mi friends .

Comment: You should consider reading a book about databases and SQL language. You have several databases choices (MySQL for example)

Comment: what database you use ? mysql,sql server, oracle etc ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Here is an example of insert into your customer table :**
- you will have to figure out the rest !

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=myTestDb;server=(local)"))
{
    SqlCommand addvalues = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO customer (id,name,age,occupation) VALUES (@id,@name,@age,@occupation)", conn);
    addvalues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bla", "bla");
    addvalues.Connection.Open();
    addvalues.ExecuteNonQuery();
    addvalues.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: how to add family members ??

Comment: i want to add family members also..how to add family members .. i think i have create another table for family members

Comment: Just follow the syntax i gave you !